# [flwr][sklearn] Trying to use Gradient Boosted Trees

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, federated-learning

for some day's now I try to implement gradient boosted tree's with flwr.
I tried the example given by [flwr](https://github.com/adap/flower/tree/main/examples/sklearn-logreg-mnist).
They use a LogisticRegression Model for the classification of MNIST, which works in my setup.

This is where my problem arise:
Simply replacing the sklear.linear_model.LogisticRegression model with the `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier` does not work because:

I don't know which values I have to initalize, which are equivalent to the `LogistiRegression.coef_`. Does anyone has an idea?

If I could make a working version I would try to add it to flwr as reference for anybody.

Thanks in advance